# How can I make buttons behind a div clickable, without using "pointer-events:none"?

Tags: html, z-index, pointer-events

I have two divs, I've placed one in front of the other using z-index. Unfortunately they must be arranged this way, changing the arrangement of the divs is not an option. The problem is that I have buttons in BOTH divs that need to be clickable. I cannot set the first div to "pointer-events:none" because that makes the top div's buttons unclickable. Is there anything I can do so that both the top div and the elements underneath are clickable?

Comment: What about changing the z-index of the buttons?

Comment: Show your HTML and a demo if possible. Answers depend on how it's structured. `z-index` may work, but it has limitations.